# automating replace and append words from text file

Tags: bash, curl

I have a line in bash file like ---

```
curl -L $domain/url1 options
```

domain is already read from another text file and 
domains like

```
abc.com
google.com
yahoo.com
```

and i have another separate file which contains further URL (lot in number):

```
url1
url2
url3
....
url1000
```

I want to replace that url and append that like:

```
curl -L abc.com/url1 options
curl -L abc.com/url2 options
curl -L abc.com/url3 options
....
curl -L $abc.com/url1000 options
```

It is taking too much time manually, so I want to automate this process.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper loop in `bash` with [Process-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst),

```
while IFS= read -r url; do
    curl -L abc.com/"$url" options
done <url_file
```

would just be sufficient (or) in a single-line of the same-loop,

```
while IFS= read -r url; do curl -L abc.com/"$url" options; done <url_file
```

---

For your updated requirement to loop on two files, you need to define multiple file descriptors and read from it,

```
while IFS= read -r domain <&3; do
    while IFS= read -r url <&4; do
        curl -L "$domain"/"$url" options
    done 4<url.txt
done 3<domain.txt
```

The above should work fine on any `POSIX` shell not involving any `bash`-isms, you could just put the above in a script with a `#!/bin/sh` she-bang.

Comment: your answer is right in normal context ,, but i am reading abc.com from already a text file that in url_file

Comment: @user7423959: You didn't mention that as part of the question. So you have two files, reading from each file on each iteration. Please provide samples of those files

Comment: @user7423959, wouldn't that be a relevant detail for the question?

Comment: @Inian, no, he should go ask another question.  You provided a fine answer to his question, you should not have to do it again.

Comment: not a problem , i will approve this answer right ,, if i not gotta any other .

Comment: yup a lot entries , more than 400-500

Comment: @user7423959: Refer my update, it should work for automating two files at once

Comment: actually wants a little bit help of you on same question for multithreading if you can .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221004/proper-use-of-and-wait-in-bash-for-mutitasking

Comment: @user7423959: This is not the standards of SO, every question is meant to be answered within its scope. This question was earlier asked and accepted. It is not recommended to ask an extension or a totally new question. New questions need to asked as per the asking guidelies.